# Node js Glob returns no file

Tags: node.js, file, glob

I am using [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) as following.

```
glob(
      `C:/master/temp/60dffca770d02959c568adb6_P+([0-9])_png.png`,
      null,
      (er, files) => {
        // Here not getting any file.
      },
    );
```

And I do have file as following.

```
C:\master\temp\60dffca770d02959c568adb6_P4_png.png
```

But no file is returning in response.

I also tested this pattern in the following link and it seems to be working there as well.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=C%3A%2FMaster%2FTemp%2F60dffca770d02959c568adb6_P%2B%28%5B0-9%5D%29_png.png&matches=false&tests=C%3A%2FMaster%2FTemp%2F60dffca770d02959c568adb6_P55_png.png

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine when I run on my system, with diff pattern. It seems the path you gave seems incorrect. The syntax seems different for the path used and the sample path. Try this:

```
glob(
      `C:\master\temp\60dffca770d02959c568adb6_P+([0-9])_png.png`,
      null,
      (er, files) => {
        // Here not getting any file.
        console.log(files);
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

**glob** is just for matching files, but when it comes to actually reading the contents of the files and additional solution will need to be used in conjunction with glob.

```
glob('C:\master\temp\60dffca770d02959c568adb6_P+([0-9])_png.png', function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            files.forEach(function (file) {
                fs.readFile(file, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(data.toString());
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause. It was an error from my end.

Actually, long GUID confused me and found that actually there were different characters in path even though in question I had kept same.

There is no error in the code. Working fine. Just I was passing the wrong document id for which file was not there.